# Data structure that allows fast access to substrings within structured text?

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

I have some largish (a few KB, maybe 1 MB max) strings in memory, they contain structured text like the example below:

```
Def[prop=A, ... some more kv pairs]
  SubDef[prop=B, ... some more kv pairs]
    SubSubDef[prop=C, ... some more kv pairs]
    ... goes deeper ...
Def[prop=X, ... some more kv pairs]
  SubDef[prop=Y, ... some more kv pairs]
    SubSubDef[prop=Z, ... some more kv pairs]
    ... goes deeper ...
SubDef[prop=Y, ... some more kv pairs]   <- yeah, SubDef can also be on level 1
  SubSubDef[prop=Z, ... some more kv pairs]
```

I will need to read these strings from file and then "query" them for data. For example, a query would be: `Def[].SubDef[].prop[]` which will mean give me all `prop` inside all `SubDef` which are inside a `Def`.

My idea was when I read the file structure, I can somehow index keywords which denote the structure. Like, I can keep an array of the position of all `Def` strings, all `SubDef` and all `SubSubDef`, so when I need to search for `SubDef` properties, I can just jump to the offsets of these keywords within the whole string.

I wonder if there is some general data structure for that? Basically it's some kind of graph? Not really a tree, because `SubDef` can also be on level 1.

To clarify, there are a lot of keywords in that string, but I only care about a subset of them.

Is there any general data structure to represent the offsets of keywords within a structured string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a tree, where on first level you have root with tree child elements: def, def and subdef.

Convert your structure to the tree, and then for querying you can use any algorithm (even XPath)

Comment: I had time to revisit the problem and yes, I agree, it makes sense to model it as a tree. Additionally I will keep track of the tree levels in a list, so I can quickly access all nodes on level N. Thanks for your suggestion.